# Can we add pause button when roku ads playing?

Tags: roku, brightscript, double-click-advertising

Can we add pause functionality to pause the ads after specific time?

Actually I'm using Roku advertising with scene graph and want to pause ads after specific time.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Ads using RAF always offer user/viewer to pause the ad while play, and are customizable in the sense that programmer can make them skippable or not.
hope that answers your query.